# Pipe using API call - how?

Tags: angular

My db is basically like this:

```
ID | SubjectCode
1 | 1
2 | 2,3
3 | 1,3
4 | 1,4

ID | SubjectName
1 | English
2 | Math
3 | History
4 | Physical Education
```

And the API call would return object containing the subject's code, not the name:

```
{
  ID: 1
  Name: Mark
  SubjectCode: 1
},
{
  ID: 2
  Name: Edu
  SubjectCode: 2,3
},
{
  ID: 3
  Name: Wally
  SubjectCode: 1,3
},
```

So when I get the list from API call, I would like to show the subject's name, not the code. There is another API call to get the name of the subject. I can do an API call for every pipe, but that sounds like a bad idea. What's the better way of doing this?

```
<td>{{student.subjectCode | convertToName}}</td>

transform(value: string, characters: string) : string {
    // Looks like a bad idea, since I need to call the backend for every value in the list?
    var subjName = GetSubjectNameById();
}
```

Comment: I'd either pass name from backend along or forkJoin the call to get students and all subject names beforehand and then either map them or pass all subject names as parameter to pipe so it can lookup the name locally. you could also setup a service call to get the name by id to cache ids and only make a call when the one requested hasn't been loaded before

Comment: you should change the response from the backend. make an inner join on the tables. otherwise you are bound to call the backend twice.

Comment: @Garine well, there is that option.. I just want to make sure that I did everything I could on my end first before changing the backend. Calling twice (once to get the page, once to get the names?) wouldn't be much of a problem (it's for intranet so most likely the page is going to be hit less than 100 times per day), but I don't want to call the backend close to hundred times just on this page alone.